# Best way to locate this element in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

For example, here's part of the source:

```
<div id = "eg_1_2_3_0399483" style = "visibility: visible; display: block;">
    <iframe id = "default_23342522" src="http://example.com/random_string_skdfjgklsjklf" style = "height: 600px;">
...

<div id = "eg_238_2348927" style = "visibility: hidden; display: none;">
    <iframe ...
```

You see, there's multiple `iframe` in the source, what I really want to locate is `<iframe id = "default_23342522" src="http://example.com/random_string_skdfjgklsjklf" style = "height: 600px;">` but as the `id` and `src` keep changing each time you load the page, so basically I would first locate `<div id = "eg_1_2_3_0399483" style = "visibility: visible; display: block;">` then go for its child node, the problem is, how do you do that? Well I know the way to locate the first `<div>` element is like this：

```
element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='visibility: visible; display: block;']")
```

And then?

Or maybe some better ideas on how to locate the `iframe` element above?

Comment: CSS style attributes are quite fragile, I wouldn't use those to identify an element. Better to use a path from an element with a non-changing ID or specific class combination. Then, you can simply do `//path/to/div/iframe[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
element = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@style='visibility: visible; display: block;']/iframe[@style='height: 600px;']")
```

If you want only the first iframe in the specified div each time (as shown in your answer), do then

```
iframe=element[0]
```

If you want to extract what is inside the iframe then you can do this:

```
iframe_content = iframe.text
```

An alternative way to locate the first iframe of the specified div is by using a similar function that returns one item instead of a list:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@style='visibility: visible; display: block;']/iframe[1]")
```

Above we used **find_element_by_xpath** instead of **find_elements_by_xpath** to just locate the first iframe of the specified div. Take in mind that I didn't specified the iframe by its style (e.g. height: 600px). But this can be done here too in a similar way as I explained above using find_elements_by_xpath.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate! I didn't know you could use xpath like that, would start to learn some xpath soon!

Comment: I'm glad that I was able to help you! PLease mark my answer as correct if you want. :)